# MapTypeStyle in MapKit

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios5, dictionary, mapkit

I wonder to know if there is any way to configure our MapKit maps like we do with the MapTypeStyle object in the Google Maps API.

If I refer to Apple doc's, MKMapView has a mapType option that takes [MKMapType constant](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205) but no styles parameters like MapOptions with the [MapTypeStyle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyle) and the [MapTypeStyler](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyler) wich is very powerfull for fast maps customizing.

So my question is : Is there any way to achieve something similar with the MapKit framework, if not, what is the best framework/library to do this ? I'm thinking of [MapBox](http://mapbox.com/) and similar products.

Comment: You can modify the colors of the MKMapView by altering a private class, but i am pretty sure apple will not allow this . If you nevertheless interested in this option, i will post you an example code.

Comment: @Lee Armstrong i added a short sample-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options for you my friend. You could use one of these frameworks

http://cloudmade.com/products/iphone-sdk

https://github.com/route-me/route-me

Or you could just use mapbox. Their api looks pretty good. 
Alternatively you supply you own map tiles and overlay mapkit. Something like this in a MKOverlayView

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context {

NSURL* fileURL = [(HeatMap*)self.overlay localUrlForStyle:@"alien" withMapRect:mapRect andZoomScale:zoomScale];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL ];
if (imageData != nil) {
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"aTileX.png"];
    // Perform the image render on the current UI context
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    [img drawInRect:[self rectForMapRect:mapRect] blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
    }
}
```

Also check this out if you want unsupported "terrain" mode
 http://openradar.appspot.com/9621632

I'm actually in the middle of a program that requires overlaying tiles over a map. [This example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/HazardMap/Introduction/Intro.html) has been very helpful. You'll want to look into MKOverlay and MKOverlayView. The project that I am doing involves using [gheat](http://code.google.com/p/gheat/). I am accessing the tiles through an NSURLConnection and storing them locally. A [gist](https://gist.github.com/2641246) of my implementation.

Comment: The custom tiles option seems to be the best approach in my case, as my map is limited into one city bounds, with few zoom levels. I'll dig this, if there is any way to store tiles locally, I'll probably use this solution for production.
Could you refer some more information/links about overlaying in your answer so I mark this question as accepted ?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to customize the map styles natively with mapkit.  Your only option for this is to opt for a hybrid app approach, and then customize the styles using html/javascript in the page itself.

Comment: This is a smart and simple solution, but not one I can use in my case. I upvoted so people can see this solution that can fit someone else needs.

Answer (score 2):

As drawing the tiles takes place in a private class called `MKMapTileView` you can not simply write a category. You have to implement another class for the custom drawing. The Methods of this class will be used to overload the implementation of `MKMapTileView` during runtime:

Header file:

```
@interface MyColorMap : NSObject
+ (void)overLoadMethods:(Class)destinationClass;
@end
```

Imlementation:

```
#import "MyColorMap.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation MyColorMap

+ (void)overLoadMethods:(Class)destinationClass {
    // get the original method for drawing a tile
    Method originalDrawLayer = class_getInstanceMethod(destinationClass, @selector(drawLayer:inContext:));

    // get the method we will replace with the original implementation of 'drawLayer:inContext:' later
    Method backupDrawLayer = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], @selector(backupDrawLayer:inContext:));

    // get the method we will use to draw our own colors
    Method myDrawLayer = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], @selector(myDrawLayer:inContext:));

    // dito with the implementations
    IMP impOld = method_getImplementation(originalDrawLayer);
    IMP impNew = method_getImplementation(myDrawLayer);

    // replace the original 'drawLayer:inContext:' with our own implementation
    method_setImplementation(originalDrawLayer, impNew);

    // set the original 'drawLayer:inContext:' implementation to our stub-method, so wie can call it later on
    SEL selector = method_getName(backupDrawLayer);
    const char *types = method_getTypeEncoding(backupDrawLayer);
    class_addMethod(destinationClass, selector, impOld, types);
}


- (void)backupDrawLayer:(CALayer*)l inContext:(CGContextRef)c {
    // stub method, implementation will never be called. The only reason we implement this is so we can call the original method durring runtime
}

- (void)myDrawLayer:(CALayer*)l inContext:(CGContextRef)c {
    // set background to white so wie can use it for blendmode
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]); 
    CGContextFillRect(c, CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(c));

    // set blendmode so the map will show as grayscale
    CGContextSetBlendMode(c, kCGBlendModeLuminosity);
    // kCGBlendModeExclusion for inverted colors etc.

    // calling the stub-method which will become the original method durring runtime
    [self backupDrawLayer:l inContext:c];

    // if you want more advanced manipulations you can alter the context after drawing:

//    int w = CGBitmapContextGetWidth(c);
//    int h = CGBitmapContextGetHeight(c);
//    
//    unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData(c);
//    if (data != NULL) {
//        int maxY = h;
//        for(int y = 0; y<maxY; y++) {
//            for(int x = 0; x<w; x++) {
//                
//                int offset = 4*((w*y)+x);
//                char r = data[offset];
//                char g = data[offset+1];
//                char b = data[offset+2]; 
//                char a = data[offset+3]; 
//                
//                // do what ever you want with the pixels
//                
//                data[offset] = r;
//                data[offset+1] = g; 
//                data[offset+2] = b;
//                data[offset+3] = a;
//            }
//        }
//    }
}
```

now you have to call `[MyColorMap overLoadMethods:NSClassFromString(@"MKMapTileView")]` at some point before using a `MKMapView`

Comment: This seems like a deep hack for a so simple need :) I'll probably use overlaying (see @jb1a1 answer) since I don't see the benefit of using your solution. Still a good thing to know. Thanks for sharing this sample.
Hope MapKit will upgrade soon and let us customize maps the JS way.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with iOS 6's MKMapView control.  Does this version not use "MKMapTileView", perhaps ?

Comment: in iOS 6 the map is completly refactored. Most of the new rendering uses openGL and this hack does not work anymore.