# Is it possible to change Apple Map colors?

Tags: ios, colors, mapkit

I've currently developing an iOS application with a dark theme, and would really like to make the displayed Apple Map also in dark colors.

I've Googled the topic and tried to change the properties of the component through the Storyboard. But, I couldn't find anything.

Is this even possible? Can I change the colors of the Apple Map component... or even just invert the color to make it look dark?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if any of the answers here might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354925 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364374

Comment: Thank you. However, overlay doesn't look like something that can give the MKMap a black theme.
And I would really like to stay with Apple Maps, and don't switch to Google or any other 3rd party providers.

Comment: I am having same requirement for customization of map theme. How did you achieve than?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little clumsy and limited, but you could put a `UIView` with black background color and  alpha less than 1.0 (e.g. 0.3) over the map (make sure to turn off user interaction with this view so gestures get passed through to the map) and that would dim the whole thing. A little kludgy and you lose contrast, but it might be worth trying.

Comment: It's a nice idea. But it's simply not enough... Especially with iOS7.
I would really love it to be inverted :/

Comment: @thedp Agreed. I suggested it with trepedation, so hopefully some of the links I posted above might be more promising. Sadly, MapKit just doesn't do this gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without using third-party providers like [MapBox](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk), at least on iOS 6 and below.

Comment: MapBox is not free. And I can't find info regarding Google Maps. Does Gmaps support a dark theme?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass of `MKTileOverlay` like

```swift
class DarkModeMapOverlay: MKTileOverlay {
    init() {
        super.init(urlTemplate: nil)
        canReplaceMapContent = true
    }

    override func url(forTilePath path: MKTileOverlayPath) -> URL {
        let tileUrl = "https://a.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/\(path.z)/\(path.x)/\(path.y).png"
        return URL(string: tileUrl)!
    }
  }
```

and then set the overlay on your `MKMapView` with

```swift
class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    private var tileRenderer: MKTileOverlayRenderer?

    private var mapView: MKMapView {
        return view as! MKMapView
    }

    private func configureTileRenderer() {
        let darkModeOverlay = DarkModeMapOverlay()
        tileRenderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(tileOverlay: darkModeOverlay)
        mapView.addOverlay(darkModeOverlay, level: .aboveLabels)
    }

    override func loadView() {
        view = MKMapView(frame: .zero)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.delegate = self
        configureTileRenderer()
    }

    // MARK: MKMapViewDelegate
    func mapView(_: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        guard let renderer = self.tileRenderer else {
            return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        }
        return renderer
    }
}
```